# "InstantiationException: zero argument constructor" ---> How to do it?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, service, instantiationexception

I have already read things about that but can't find a way to fix my problem anyway (Beginner here...)
So, I'm currently developping an Android Studio App.
I have just done fragments to have different tab on a screen.
Previously I have done a "bluetooth and a bluetoothService" activity who was perfectly working.
However, since I have implements these fragments I got this error

```
 java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.thibaud.dogbotapp.bluetoothService> has no zero argument consde here
```

So I have tried to do an empty constructor but I don't know how to do it properly...

This is the begin of my bluetoothService class :

```
public class bluetoothService  {


private static final String TAG = "bluetoothService";

private static final String appName = "DogBot";

private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

private final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;



Context mContext;

private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
private UUID deviceUUID;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;


/*public bluetoothService(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    start();
}*/
```

start() method here :

```
 public synchronized void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
}
```

Well, first post here sorry if it's not perfect, hope you guys will be able to help !
Thanksar

Comment: `public bluetoothService(){}` Classes should start with an uppercase.

Answer (score -1):

A zero-argument constructor is declared like so:

```
public ClassName() {
//Constructor tasks go here
}
```

Hope it helps

*EDIT:*

And yes, as davidxxx stated, you should always start class names with upper case letters. e.g. `ClassName` as opposed to `className`. Variable names, however, start with lower case such as `variableName`.

Comment: Hum actually I know that but, it's about the arguments I have in my initial constructor, I have no idea of how to initialize them without a constructor...

Comment: If I understand what you mean correctly (let me know if not), then each class **must** have a constructor (an empty, zero-argument one at the minimum). You cannot have a class without a constructor.

Comment: Yes ok but how could I inisialize that then 
    mContext = context;
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    start();

Comment: I understand the `context` is a formal argument. Depending on what is being called there may be a way to instantiate `context` to a variable which could be set as `mContext`. You could initialize `btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();` `start();` as normal because they are not reliant on an argument. Also, could you use the `this` keyword for setting `mContext` in part of your code?

Comment: This is not the answer anybody is looking for, we know how to create a zero arg constructor.